# Enlarging the text of a wide table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a wide table in `beamer`. I adjusted the table width by `resizebox`. But the texts in the table are not visible.  How can I enlarge the text ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

        \begin{table}
        \caption{Characteristics of studies of cardiovascular disease risk in individuals with and without cardiovascular risk factors.}                                
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{

        \begin{tabular}{l l l l l l }\\
            Study & Country & Journal & Risk Factor & Study size (No. with risk factors) & No. of cases (No. of cases with risk factors)\\
            \hline
            Wilson 1998 & United States& American Heart Association&Hypertension&68211(21577)&610(321)\\
            \hline
            Asia Pacific Cohort Studies Collaboration 2003 & Asia, Australia, and New Zealand & DIABETES CARE & Diabetes & 160555(4812)&3635(250)\\
            \hline
            Iqbal 2012 & Pakistan & Middle-East Journal of Scientific Research & Hypertension & 600(253) & 344(170)\\
            \hline
            Kannel 1979 & United States & American Heart Association & Diabetes & 34621(2506)& 1049(148)\\
            \hline 
            Vasan 2001 & United States & The New England Journal of Medicine &  Hypertension & 3979(1794) & 316(180)\\
            \hline
            Din 2007 & Pakistan & Pakistan Journal of Statistics and Operation Research & Diabetes & 700(150) & 500(143)\\
            \hline
            Din 2007 & Pakistan & Pakistan Journal of Statistics and Operation Research & Hypertension & 700(240) & 500(214)\\
            \hline
            Fraser 1992 & United States & American Heart Association & Diabetes & 53628(1825) & 99(11)\\
            \hline
            Fraser 1992 & United States & American Heart Association & Hypertension & 53628(8161) & 99(30)\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
        \end{table}                     

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is a good example of why using `\resizebox` to attempt to make it fit inside the text block may cause more problems than it solves.

I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment to let LaTeX insert line breaks. It's still necessary to switch to a smaller font size; below, I suggest using `\scriptsize`, for a 30% linear reduction of the font size. I also suggest using abbreviations and acronyms, e.g., "NEJM" instead of "The New England Journal of Medicine". If need be, the acronyms may be spelled out below the `tabularx` environment, at the bottom of the frame.

Incidentally, in `beamer` documents, `table` environments don't "float" (in the LaTeX sense of the word). There's little point in using them in the first place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Characteristics of studies of cardiovascular disease risk in individuals with and without cardiovascular risk factors

\smallskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{6}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
Study & Country & Journal & Risk Factor & Study size  (No.\ with risk factors) & No.\ of cases  (No.\ of cases with risk factors)\\
\midrule
Wilson 1998 & USA& AHA&Hypertension&68211 (21577)&610 (321)\\
\addlinespace[2pt]
APCSC 2003 & Asia, Australia, NZ & Diabetes Care & Diabetes & 160555 (4812)&3635 (250)\\
\addlinespace[2pt]
Iqbal 2012 & Pakistan & MEJSRH & Hypertension & 600 (253) & 344 (170)\\
\addlinespace[2pt]
Kannel 1979 & USA & AHA & Diabetes & 34621 (2506)& 1049 (148)\\
\addlinespace[2pt] 
Vasan 2001 & USA & NEJM &  Hypertension & 3979 (1794) & 316 (180)\\
\addlinespace[2pt]
Din 2007 & Pakistan & PJSOR & Diabetes & 700 (150) & 500 (143)\\
\addlinespace[2pt]
Din 2007 & Pakistan & PJSOR & Hypertension & 700 (240) & 500 (214)\\
\addlinespace[2pt]
Fraser 1992 & USA & AHA & Diabetes & 53628 (1825) & 99 (11)\\
\addlinespace[2pt]
Fraser 1992 & USA & AHA & Hypertension & 53628 (8161) & 99 (30)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip\tiny
APCSC: Asia Pacific Cohort Studies Collaboration; AHA: American Heart Association; MEJSRH: Middle-East Journal of Scientific Research; PJSOR: Pakistan Journal of Statistics and Operation Research

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```